# Rails: Case insensitive params hash keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can the params hash in Rails normalize keys to be case-insensitive?

If Rails receives a `GET` request with the following query params `http://localhost.com:3000/username?debug=true&vErBoSe=true`

`params[:verbose]` will be `nil` and you'd need to use `params[:vErBoSe]` to get the value.

Comment: Unlike the linked question the params hash is coming from outside the system via a URL or POST body. A simple way to handle this is adjust it in the controller. Ruby 2.5 introduced [`Hash#transform_keys!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21) which would allow a simple `params.transform_keys! { _1.downcase }`.

Comment: NO LONGER A DUPLICATE. In Rails 7  in 2022 the params object has a dedicated method for this: `params.deep_transform_keys!(&:downcase)`

Reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-deep_transform_keys-21

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert the params hash into one which handles keys case insensitively, before accessing its values.

Ryan McGeary has an example implementation of a case insensitive hash over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030565/454094, which I have copied below:

```
require "active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access"

class CaseInsensitiveHash < HashWithIndifferentAccess
  # This method shouldn't need an override, but my tests say otherwise.
  def [](key)
    super convert_key(key)
  end

  protected

  def convert_key(key)
    key.respond_to?(:downcase) ? key.downcase : key
  end  
end
```

With it, you could do:

```
CaseInsensitiveHash.new(params)[:verbose]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to make the keys simple and follow convention. By making all keys lowercase / downcase. If you need a value, then you downcase the variable then pass it to the hash.

The hash:

```
params = {key: 'Hello', another_key: 'World'}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
params[var.downcase]
```

Comment: It sounds like you are saying to add all keys already in lowercase, but the question asks for a situation where the hash is already generated by rails from the URL...meaning that is not an option!

Comment: I understand what the question is saying. And my answer still remains the same. As a senior rails developer, I have yet to need to lowercase an uri, and from his example localhost url, it indicates he is doing the uppercasing. So this question is like 'How do I use goto and not get spaghetti code?'. The answer is, don't use goto. For this, don't have uppercase parameters in the first place.