# Where do I place a file that exntends the hash class in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, hash, helper

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.1.  I want to create a case insensitive hash as described here — [How do I create a hash in Ruby that compares strings, ignoring case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030336/how-do-i-create-a-hash-in-ruby-that-compares-strings-ignoring-case) .  I have created the file, app/active-support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb, with

```
class CaseInsensitiveHash < HashWithIndifferentAccess
  # This method shouldn't need an override, but my tests say otherwise.
  def [](key)
    super convert_key(key)
  end

  protected

  def convert_key(key)
    key.respond_to?(:downcase) ? key.downcase : key
  end  
end
```

but when I load up my console, its not recognizing the hash …

```
davea$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)
2.3.0 :001 > h = CaseInsensitiveHash.new
NameError: uninitialized constant CaseInsensitiveHash
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Where do I place my file so that it can be picked up in my project?

Comment: `config/initializers/` is the mostly used place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually put that stuff in lib/core_ext/hash.rb. But it's up to you. What I do that you're missing is create a config/initializers/require.rb file that looks like this:

```
require "core_ext/hash"
require "core_ext/array"
...
```