# Regex with Regex.union but case insensitive gsub find and replace

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to do a case-insensitive word-based 'find and replace' on a string. I have this:

```
string = "12 aaa aAa AAA aaaword ddd"
dict_texts = {"aaa" => "bBb", "ccc" => "dDd"}
```

I want this:

```
"12 bBb b8b b8b aaaword ddd"
```

I did this:

```
regexp = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(dict_texts.keys).source })\b/ix
#=> /\b(?:aaa|ccc)\b/ix
string.gsub(regexp, dict_texts)
#=> "12 bBb   aaaword ddd"
```

I'm pretty close. but still having some trouble.

Comment: See [How do I create a hash in Ruby that compares strings, ignoring case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030336/how-do-i-create-a-hash-in-ruby-that-compares-strings-ignoring-case)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżI think this is a possible solution but it doesn't seem to work with gsub and rewriting more of the hash class seems like a bad idea

Comment: See the second answer. `"12 aaa aAa AAA aaaword ddd".gsub(regexp) { | x | dict_texts[x.downcase] }`. This will work as your keys are all in lower case.

Comment: BTW, wrapping a regex literal in a `Regexp.new` call is superfluous. It's like writing `String.new("foo")` instead of just `"foo"`.

Comment: I think it does matter, doesn't it? Without the wrapping, "cloudaaa" becomes "cloudaaa" which is good (i'm not sure why it doesn't work for "aaacloud" -> "bBbcloud" though)

Comment: @echan00 It works correctly in my environment. Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: @echan00 `regexp == Regexp.new(regexp) #=> true` – must be something else.

Comment: Yes, it is my error, thank you all for your help!

Comment: There is no such thing as `Regex` or `Regex.union`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either pass a block to `gsub` to [`downcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-downcase) the key: (given that all hash keys are lowercase)

```
"12 aaa aAa AAA aaaword ddd".gsub(regexp) { |s| dict_texts[s.downcase] }
#=> "12 bBb bBb bBb aaaword ddd"
```

Or use a hash with a [`default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) which does this for you:

```
dict_texts.default_proc = ->(h, k) { h.fetch(k.downcase, nil) }

"12 aaa aAa AAA aaaword ddd".gsub(regexp, dict_texts)
#=> "12 bBb bBb bBb aaaword ddd"
```

Comment: "AAAword".gsub(regexp, dict_texts) results in "bBbword" and "wordAAA".gsub(regexp, dict_texts) resuts in "wordAAA", would you know why?

Comment: Preferably, I want "wordAAA" in both cases

Comment: @echan00 your example regexp `/\b(?:aaa|ccc)\b/ix` won't match either of these because of the word boundaries `\b`.